# Rails model - how to differentiate different types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am currently working on a nested model form.
I have a subject model.
This subject model has lessons of 3 different types - tutorial, lecture and laboratory.

I am able to get the nested form working with https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.
But I want to fix it such that in the form only 3 forms for the child(lesson model) will be produced and that their first field (lesson_type field) will be automatically filled in and fixed.

I am not too sure on how to model such a situation on Rails.
These are the codes I have so far.
Any advice on what I could try out or point out the mistakes I have made would be appreciated.

This is the form.
Right now I could get the form to show up three times on my controller but I am not sure how I could generate different values for the fields. They are all showing lecture as of now.

```
<%= nested_form_for(@subject, :remote=>true) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :subject_code %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :subject_code %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :lessons do |lesson_form| %>
     <%= lesson_form.label :lesson_type %><br/>
     <%= lesson_form.text_field :lesson_type, :value=> "lecture"%><br/>
     <%= lesson_form.label :name %><br/>
     <%= lesson_form.text_field :name %><br/>

  <%= lesson_form.fields_for :lesson_groups do |lesson_group_form| %>

       <%= lesson_group_form.label :group_index %><br/>
       <%= lesson_group_form.text_field :group_index %>
       <%= lesson_group_form.link_to_remove "Remove this task" %>

  <% end %>

  <p><%= lesson_form.link_to_add "Add a lesson_group",:lesson_groups,:id=>"open-lesson"%></p>

 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is the controller. The creation will happen on the index page.

```
  def index
    @subjects = Subject.all
    @subject = Subject.new

    lecture = @subject.lessons.build
    lecture.lesson_groups.build
    lecture.destroy

    tutorial = @subject.lessons.build
    tutorial.lesson_groups.build
    tutorial.destroy

    laboratory = @subject.lessons.build
    laboratory.lesson_groups.build
    laboratory.destroy


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @subjects }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

The subject model

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :subject_code, :lessons_attributes
  has_many :lessons, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lessons, :allow_destroy => :true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:lesson_type].blank? }

end
```

And the lesson model

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject
  attr_accessible :lesson_type, :name, :subject, :lesson_groups_attributes
  has_many :lesson_groups, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lesson_groups, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I am not sure if this is to the Rails convention but I got it working according to what I want. Added the following lines in the subject model: Basically assigning the lesson type field in the model.

```
lecture = @subject.lessons.build
lecture.lesson_type = "lecture"
lecture.lesson_groups.build
lecture.destroy

tutorial = @subject.lessons.build
tutorial.lesson_type = "tutorial"
tutorial.lesson_groups.build
tutorial.destroy

laboratory = @subject.lessons.build
laboratory.lesson_type = "laboratory"
laboratory.lesson_groups.build
laboratory.destroy
```

And to make it such that they can't change the lesson type I made it read only

```
 <%= lesson_form.text_field :lesson_type, :readonly=>true%><br/>
```